# How to add Google's ReCaptcha to form

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, captcha, recaptcha

I've read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display), but it doesn't say how to put it on Zend properly. Can anyone explain how it's done ?

Comment: It's built in. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.service.recaptcha.html or http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.captcha.adapters.html#zend-captcha-recaptcha depending on your Zend version

Comment: It's the same for Zend 2, however it uses the old version of it, and the new one is much better.